# Как определяется срок Non-renewing подписки в Apple Purchase?

Tags: ios, apple, appstore

Не вижу возможности задать срок действия невозобновляемой подписки при ее создании.

Этот срок нужно определять и контроливать самостоятельно в приложении или это все таки задается где-то в настройках покупок?

Можно ли создать невозобновляемую подписку на 24 часа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Длительность невозобновляемой подписки (в отличие от подписки с автоматическим продлением) не задается в itunesconnect, а отслеживается приложением.

Ответ нашел тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527660/